# How do I save python code in JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization

I've got a large python project with several components, that exchange information with JSON files. Actually, this project is our internal tool for analysis and integration testing, and our developers use it either from web-UI, or from a command line.

The python modules process a labeled database, consisting of large amount of files, and labels are encoded in file names. For example, file name `ab001l_AS_5_15Fps_1.raw` contains information that it stores data from user `ab001l`, collected in session number 1 under conditions, that we encode as `AS`.

There are several such encodings exist.

JSON files usually store file names.

My question is: how can I save a python code into JSON file, so that another module could load it and decode file name into components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can store python code as text in JSON, then use the `exec` built-in function to *execute* the text. See
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec.

But it seems a much better approach to share your module and import your module like any python code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/). Please check the documentation page for usage.

```
import jsonpickle


class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

obj = Thing('Awesome')

frozen = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
thawed = jsonpickle.decode(frozen)
```